# I have a substring that works but sometime the word that i'm using is not in the comment

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column that has comments the word additional comments: should be in the there with the rest of the text but sometime it's not. 
Example; Patient took info Additional Comments: call patient.. In this case i want to return call  Patient. 
But if I only have Patient took info and he will come back. I don't want to return anything.

```
SUBSTRING(shortnote, Charindex('additional Comments:', shortnote)  + len('additional comments:'), LEN(shortnote))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` statement:

```
(case when shortnote like '%additional Comments:%'
      then SUBSTRING(shortnote,
                     (Charindex('additional Comments:', shortnote) +
                      len('additional comments:') + 1, LEN(shortnote)
                    )
 end)
```

This returns `NULL`, if the pattern is not found.  If you want to filter out the rows entirely, use `where`:

```
where shortnote like '%additional Comments:%'
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great I was wondering if you can help me with this it works but I get an extra letter from the ending word. this return the value in between the 2 words

Comment: SUBSTRING(LEFT(shortnote, CHARINDEX('Physician notified:', shortnote)), 
  CHARINDEX('Type:', shortnote) + LEN('Type:') + 1, LEN(shortnote)) as Type,